# Connecting 2 positive leads from the same car battery to a light

Tags: current, dc, automotive, lighting

I just installed some small daytime running LEDs ([LED lights used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6fpJ5Ytgkk&list=PLJVxXkaMPSYEif2YJLFvC9XPXljK5E9A_&index=2)) which also acts as an animated turn signal when the original signal is blinking. The positive lead that is attached to power the light only supplies power when my headlights are turned on, which is kind of an issue. Although, when I unlock my vehicle, and the original turn signal lights come on, and the animated lights turn on, which is a cool effect.

My main question is, can I leave the positive lead on the LED and also tap in a constant positive lead for when my lights are off? I was going to tap into the fuse tap for the USB connector to supply that constant power, so even if my headlights are off, the turn signal will still work. Just wondering if I am going to mess up anything by providing 2 positive leads to one light, and if the current would flow back and damage anything?

[image: Here's a rough layout of what I am asking]

I am still learning, so I appreciate the replies in advance!

Comment: In your under-dash fuse-block you should have an empty "Acc" (accessory) port and possibly an empty power port. The accessory port is operative with Key-on or key in the accessory position (powers radio, etc..). If you have a power port that will provide always-on power (used to go to cigarette lighter in older cars). I would encourage you to come off the fuse-block to your lights and avoid a dual-power setup (unless you diode each power lead properly) You don't want to feed power to the actual turn signal through your USB power -- that could cause issues.

Comment: Your link to the video shows only tapping power from the turn signal lights themselves. (they have dual-filament turn signals that also provide running lights). Is the problem you are trying to solve the lack of a running light indication with your turn signal?

Comment: If connected as shown in the picture the Turn Signal Light will remain on. You need to add a diode in the wire from the bulb to the rest of the circuit. Anode of the diode points to the bulb. What turns the power off when you leave the car?

Comment: I think I may have solved my own issue. It looks like the power source where I am powering everything turns on when I unlock/lock my vehicle, so I am getting the animation then which is what I want, but I think the reason why the LED turn signals aren't getting powered on is because it needs that initial power source as well as power to the turn signal, which I currently don't have. I am going to rewire the constant source and attach it the ACC fuse, which @DavidC.Rankin suggested, & that should fix this issue. I think I just had a sudden brain fart when I posted the first question. Thank you!